# popupCentered link from entire <TR> shown in fullscreen. I want a smaller popup?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have entire table row clickable to a popup window for the chessgame.

I went to http://thephuse.com/design-and-usability/clickable-table-rows-with-jquery/ which tells me add  and adds:

```
<!-- make entire <tr> clickable-->
<script>
jQuery( function($) {$('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click(
function(){window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');}).find('a').hover(
function() {$(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');},
function() {$(this).parents('tr').click( function()
{window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');});});});
</script>
```

But that results in a fullscreen browser window. I want a centered popup like this script creates:

```
<!--popup centered window-->
<script>function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h)
{var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);} </script>
```

Yes, I tried

```
<tr class="PopupCenter" data-href="http://google.com">
```

but the resulting popup is still fullscreen; as you can see from the games table at 
    http://chesstao.com/test-2.php

the PopupCenter class isn't applied.

What can I do?

Adding:

```
<tr onclick="PopupCenter('games/$game', 'myPop1',400,400);"> dw
```

I am trying another solution, but this one also has an interesting bug. This time I am using the pop-up code of the photographer credit under the photo at http://chesstao.com/test-2.php
I want to click anywhere on a  and have the popup appear.

The  clickable code:

```
<script>
jQuery( function($) {$('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click(
function(){temp($(this).attr('data-href');}).find('a').hover(
function() {$(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');},
function() {$(this).parents('tr').click( function()
{temp($(this).attr('data-href');});});});
</script>

<!--Another Pop-up for diagram--> 
<script src="js/jquery.popupWindow-min.js" ></script>
<script>$('.diagram-popup').popupWindow({height:500, width:800}); </script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<tr class="gradeA" data-href="games/BG-1001.php" ><td>07/17/1998</td><td>EU-ch U12</td>
<td>Mureck</td><td>0000</td><td>Khramiankov, Yuri</td><td>B99
</td><td style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">games/BG-1001.php</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace both

```
window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
```

with

```
PopupCenter($(this).attr('data-href'), "Some Title", 100, 100);
```

or whatever size window you want

Note: you need to have `PopupCenter` defined in your script somewhere in order to make use of it.

The full answer would be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click(
        function(){
            PopupCenter($(this).attr('data-href'), 'title', 100, 100)
        }
    ).find('a').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').click( 
                function() {
                    PopupCenter($(this).attr('data-href'), 'title', 100, 100);
                }
            );
        }
    );
});

function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, ' + 
        'directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, ' + 
        'copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}

</script>
```

You would need to supply the title, and the correct height and width values. But that's basically it, I think.

Comment: <!-- make entire <tr> clickable
    <script>
    jQuery( function($) {$('tbody tr[data-href]').addClass('clickable').click(
    function(){window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');}).find('a').hover(
    function() {$(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');},
    function() {$(this).parents('tr').click( function()
    {window.location = $(this).attr('data-href');});});});
    </script> --> But there are two occurences of: window.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); -which ones do I change?

Comment: dw.. and now clicking on a <tr> does nothing!

Comment: the script you generously supplied only works on the first table page. If I go to page 2/3, clicking on a table row dw. Also, your script re-uses the same window as it has been titled. I'd prefer it have a new pop-up window with a different title to make it less confusing.

Comment: I think it's a problem with dataTables